# Bootstrap 3 navbar active li not changing background-color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added custom CSS for the active li element of navbar. But it seems to be picking the default color. Other colors such as navbar BG and text color seems to have changes properly.

The modified CSS rules are as follows:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #7b431a;
    border-color: #d65c14;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #8a0e0b;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #8a0e0b;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #8a0e0b;
    background-color: #d65c14;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #8a0e0b;
    background-color: #d65c14;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #8a0e0b;
    border-bottom-color: #8a0e0b;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #8a0e0b;
    border-bottom-color: #8a0e0b;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #d65c14;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #d65c14;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Poducts</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
```

The output navbar is as follows:

[image: Navbar image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to add CSS to `.active` instead of `.active a`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T5X6h/2/

Something like this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active{
    color: #000;
    background: #d65c14;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #000;
    background: #d65c14;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. the issue still exists. :)

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active  {
    color: #8a0e0b;
    background: #d65c14;
}

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ?..Seems to be working for me.

Comment: So do you want to override the grey color ?

Comment: Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/T5X6h/1/

 am not sure what color you want.

Comment: color can be modified by the hex value. but the issue is that it is not picking up the color provided (be it any color)

Comment: it is ok now. Thank you . please edit the answer so that it may be marked as correct.

Comment: I have an interesting spin on this. In my boostrap 3.3.6 there is no "active" class defined for "li" or "a" in the navbar. If I probe the pages using the google developer tools no "active" class is added to the item, even if I add it in code it seems to get removed. In fact I just checked the `bootstrap.js` and there is no active class applied to navbar elements. Am I missing something `<li>
    <a href="...">Link</a>
</li>`

Answer (score 9):

In my own `bootstrap.css` that I load after the `bootstrap.min.css` only that, switch of the background image with `!important` works for me:

```
.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav > .active > a {
  color: #fff !important;

  background-color:#f4511e !important;
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Bootstrap 3.3.x make sure you use the scrollspy JavaScript capability to track active elements. It's easy to include it in your HTML. Just do the following:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="Id or class of the element you want to track">
```

In most cases I usually track active elements on my navbar, so I do the following:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top" >
```

Now in your CSS you can target `.navbar-fixed-top .active a`:

```
.navbar-fixed-top .active a { 
    // Put in some styling 
}
```

This should work if you are tracking active li elements in your top fixed navigation bar.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had a similar challenge. Using the inspect element tool in Firefox, I was able to trace the markup and the CSS used to style the link when clicked. On click, the list item (li) is given a class of .open and it's the anchor tag in the class that is formatted with the grey color background.

To fix this, just add this to your stylesheet.

```
.nav .open > a
{
    background:#759ad6;
    // Put in styling
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you include "bootstrap-theme.css" files on your code?

In "bootstrap-theme.min.css" files, background-image about ".active" is existed for "navbar" (check this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXksJ.png).

It will re-declare your style code, and then it will be effected on your code.

So after you delete or re-declare them (background-image), you can use your background color style about the ".active" tag.

Answer (score 0):

in my case just removing `background-image` from `nav-bar` item solved the problem

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    .
    .
    .


    background-image: none;
}
```