# css bootstrap use active in a list <li>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following hover effect in my stylesheet

```
ul.nav li:hover {
background:blue;
}
```

which has the desired effect to turn in blue the section of the bar when I hover over the link. Here is the template (I am using rails/bootstrap):

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Sign up", signup_path %></li>
  </ul>
```

I now want the section of the bar to remain blue when the link is active. I am trying to use the "active" function in css and tried the two following syntax

```
ul.nav li:hover li:active{
background:blue;
}
```

or a by adding a new separate paragraph in my stylesheet

```
ul.nav li:active {
background:blue;
}
```

Both of them fail. Would anyone have an idea why it fails and how I can obtain the desired effect?

EDIT

I just troubleshooted the error. If I full remove the hover effect and replace it with

```
ul.nav li:active {
background:blue;
}
```

The section gets blue just a during the click (a few miliseconds) and then gets back to the normal state. So :active, by itself does not seem to work in my stylesheet. Could any other dependency explain this issue?

Comment: First attempt will fail because `ul.nav li:hover li:active`  selects `li` elements inside `li` elements inside `ul` elements. The space in css selects descendants.

Comment: @Bastien when you give the css to the multiple selectors you must need to separate the with **,**

Comment: better use .active class in li tag

Comment: @Amit singh. Thanks this is indeed what I am trying to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732584/bootstrap-3-navbar-active-li-not-changing-background-color

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
ul.nav li:hover,ul.nav li:active {
    background:blue;
}
```

instead of

```
ul.nav li:hover li:active {
    background:blue;
}
```

You missed a comma and that changed the complete css rule

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/824/

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: @Rouven B. & @K K. Thanks for your suggestions. None of them worked though. The color disappears as soon as I stopped hovering over the link.

Comment: @Bastien  It's working. You can see the updated answer. In the browser console, try activating the active pseudo selector manually. You'll see the effect

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul.nav > li.active > a{
    background:blue;
}
```

This is why: `>` selects only direct children. `li.active` means select tag `li` witch class `active`. You also have to add the `> a` to be at least as specific as the bootstrap css rules otherwise they'll overwrite yours.

**EDIT:**
It turns out that bootstrap does not handle the class active by it's own. So you have to do that.

```
$('ul.nav > li > a').click(function() {
    $('ul.nav > li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Here is a working fiddl: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/828/