# Failed to change the currently active bootstrap navbar list item text color on click?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked many times here, but for some reason none of them work in my example. I have wasted three days without any success by looking it up on the Internet. Here is some of my research:

- *[Bootstrap 3 navbar active li not changing background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732584/bootstrap-3-navbar-active-li-not-changing-background-color)*
- *[Changing the color of active nav-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743102/changing-the-color-of-active-nav-item)*

**Note**: The below jQuery code changes the color of navbar list item, but the moment I click on the page it gets back to the default color, and it also does not display the page relative to the navbar item. Commenting out the jQuery code displays the page relative to the navbar item.

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}"> Blackbird </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav">
                <li><a href="#"> Search </a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" id="authentication" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Sign In/Up <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" class="dropdownMenu">
                        <li><a href="#"> Sign Up </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Sign In </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="nav">
                <li class="seperator"><a href="#" class="not-active"></a></li>
                <li class="selectionStyle"><a href="{% url 'articles' %}"> Article </a></li>
                <li class="selectionStyle"><a href="{% url 'contact' %}"> Contact </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus{

    color: black;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {

    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
}

/*
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > a > .active {

    color:black;
}*/

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {

    color:black;
}

.navbar-nav > .active > a {

    color: black;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#nav li a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution and here it is:

**By changing the jQuery code from this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#nav li a').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault(); // This does not allow to load the relative page to the nav item.

        $('#nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

**to this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var pathname = window.location.pathname;
  if (pathname == '/')
      $('.navbar-brand').css("color", "rgb(32, 42, 62)", "background-color", "#D3212D");
  else
        $('#nav > li > a[href="' + pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

});
```

I was able to fix my problem :)